# MessageResouce files in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

My application suppose to work with different languages. In order to provide this feature, I have created different messageResource files for each language.
Each resource files contain the same keys but values are different according to which language application is running. I load the specific language resource file on application load up.
This is working very fine.

However, as we are adding more features, the resource files for each language becoming very long, which makes it difficult to manage (edit) for non-techy person like Content editor guy.

Therefore, I would like to know, how can I redesign or remodularise in such a way that it will be easy to manage for Content Writers?
I hope I clear the scenario but please shout, if any thing needs?

Comment: For example, if i make files based on pages, then it will be multiple files for each language. Since, i can only make one resourceBundle object based on each file, how to load values from different files then

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a i18n standard mechanism in the Java world to split message properties in chunks. However, I have made good experiences with a standalone properties-edit-tool like [jLokalize](http://jlokalize.sourceforge.net/). It's pretty user-friendly even for non-programmers: hand over the properties files to the content writer and let him/her load the files in the editor.